# Large valid PDF files for testing

Tags: manual-testing, regression-testing, pdf-file

I am looking for large sample `PDF` files for testing. I know, that `PDFtk` can combine `PDF` files, but I am lookig for some prepared files for this purpose in range of 100 MB - 400 MB. These should be valid PDF files intead of randomly generated ones.

Comment: Why can't you create them yourself? Especially since you can control the content. You repeat a certain text with images for plenty of times and voila, you've got yourself 400mb pdf file

Comment: Also, you can use google advanced search to look for: `filetype:pdf` and add a `100..500 MB` query, to get [this result list](https://www.google.co.uk/search?as_q=&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=100..500+MB&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=pdf&as_rights=). [Advanced search ftw](https://www.google.co.uk/advanced_search)

Comment: Should files contain Pictures? Binaries? You can reach 500 mb easily with one page doc embedding high Res pics. Or video. Or binary. Pdf has tons of possibilities to embed and execute almost anything. It's documentation itself is probably bigger then 500 mb

Answer (score 1):

Most platforms have a printer driver that can create pdf files , I would use this as a source rather than random pdfs from the internet. PDFs can contain lots of nasty things that shouldn't be in a test environment unless you are specifically testing that you can handle them.

Comment: Large presentations , log files , test reports all should give you a hefty file , you should be able to combine multiple documents into one with the print technique.

Comment: Yes, I know and that is why I am looking for "dedicated" test files.

Comment: People who write printer drivers write the best postscript, it's a printer language